# Vendor-independent SQL syntax for dropping unique and primary key constraints

Tags: postgresql, oracle, liquibase, ddl, liquibase-sql

**Precondition:**
I am using Liquibase with SQL scripts in my app. I started testing with Oracle DB, but now I need to switch to PostgreSQL DB.

**Problem:**
When I added constraints, I didn't add the names of the constraints.
Liquibase changelog contains a script for dropping unique and primary key constraints:

```
alter table SCENARIO drop primary key/
alter table SCENARIO drop unique (OWNER_ID)/
```

This syntax doesn't sync with PostgreSQL

*Could you give some advice, on how to resolve this problem?*

**Screenshots:** [image]

Comment: If you want to write vendor independent changelogs, you should use the XML format. `<dropPrimaryKey  tableName="scenario"/>` will work on Postgres and Oracle.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, for this command I need to add "constraintName" attribute, but I don't know constraint names.

Comment: Caused by: liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
     18 changes have validation failures
          constraintName is required for dropUniqueConstraint on oracle

Comment: Works for me with Liquibase 4.10

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I added a screenshot with the error. I updated the Liquibase version.